# Repair a broken EF Databse First design project

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-database-first

Our project started out as Database design first.  Some point down the road it broke and rather than fixing it at that point individuals kept adding on top of it by adding all of the model and code generations by hand.

This of course is now adding a lot of extra work to the project.  Is it possible to repair this project so we can simple right click on the EDMX and update the model rather than having to add everything by hand?

The project gives no errors, no indication of where/when it went wrong.  But after months of doing everything by hand, enough is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following steps (**Code-First** oriented):

**1 -** Update all the classes mirrored with the database tables (not the other way around);

**2 -** `Enable-Migrations` on the **Package Manager Console**;

**3 -** `Add-Migration First` and clear all the changes from the `Up` and `Down` methods created on the `migration` generated class;

**4 -** Set all the specific more complex relationships and indexes via `Fluent` on the `Context` class;

**5 -** Call `Update-Database`;

**Don't forget to backup your database before starting.**

Comment: Would this switch the project to code first or would this let us go back to database first design?

Comment: This solution would switch the project to a Code-First oriented application. I wouldn't be able to help you with the DB First design.